# Sort array numeric before string?

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I can't sort my array so that numbers comes before `-` (hyphen).

My array today:

```
Array
(
    [-] => Test
    [0] => Test
    [1] => Test
    [2] => Test
)
```

The order I want:

```
Array
(

    [0] => Test
    [1] => Test
    [2] => Test
    [-] => Test
)
```

I have searched both here and on Google. But found no answers. I have tried experimenting with `ksort()` and `usort()`, but without success.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could create your own compare function with `uksort` which handels such special cases.

```
uksort($a, function($a, $b) {
   if (is_numeric($a) && is_numeric($b)) return $a - $b;
   else if (is_numeric($a)) return -1;
   else if (is_numeric($b)) return 1;
   return strcmp($a, $b);
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Use [natural order sorting function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.natsort.php)

`natsort()`

**example:**

```
$arr = ['_', 6, 3, 5];
natsort($arr);
print_r($arr);
```

**output:**

```
Array
(
    [2] => 3
    [3] => 5
    [1] => 6
    [0] => _
)
```

If you want to sort by keys then you can use ksort() function with flag **SORT_NATURAL** `ksort($arr, SORT_NATURAL);`

**example:**

```
$arr = [
   '_' => 'test',
    6  => 'test', 
    3  => 'test', 
    5  => 'test'
];

ksort($arr, SORT_NATURAL);
```

Comment: so he can use ksort with flag SORT_NATURAL

Answer (score 0):

function check($x, $y){
    if(is_numeric($x) && !is_numeric($y))
        return 1; 
    else if(!is_numeric($x) && is_numeric($y)) 
        return -1; 
    else 
        return ($x < $y) ? -1 : 1; 
} 
$array = array("-", "1", "2", "3");
usort ( $array , 'check' );